# How to convert pdf to doc file in java

Tags: java, php, pdf, documentation-generation

need to convert a pdf file to a doc file. I found different type of example to generate pdf file but not got pdf to doc.

Comment: Which version of PDF and especially DOC are you referring to?

Comment: That's a whole PROGRAM you're talking about. That is nothing you can do with 20 well placed lines of code. Companies are SELLING those should give you a good idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your asking is actually very difficult

I recommend you start [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries) and look for a good parsing library. then you would have to write it out in .doc format. Inevitably a lot of the formatting and extra information would be lost. it would be a lot easier to output to docx format, but i assume thats not what your looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much to give some idea in this regards

Answer (score 0):

I see few possible solutions:

1. [Davisor Publishor 6.2](http://www.davisor.com/publishor/) probably can be used, but it is commercial, and seems that generates only txt from pdf... just have a look
2. parse pdf with [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), and then
   generate doc with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) -
   another way to try (free one ;)
3. look for command line tools, like
   [Convert PDF To DOC](http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-Doc/Features/Convert-PDF-To-Doc.htm) and execute
   them from java

Otherwise take a look at Con's answer, there is a link to the list with java pdf processing libraries, maybe some library can do it directly, or can be used to parse pdf (better than iText), and then just use Apache POI to generate doc. Hope it helps ;)